# HTML image centered in a division for mobile perspectives

Tags: html, css

since 6 hours I'm trying to produce the following output on my different mobile devices:
[image]

As you can guess there are two different pictures: The background of a joystick and the joystick itself that should be draggable.

Whatever I try: It looks different on other devices or if I turn my device or something..
What I wish to achieve: The picture like you see it should have a width of 70%. That seems to work.. but I can't place my stick exactly into the middle.

I was trying with images, divisons with backgrounds, percentage-values, absolute and relative positions but now its time for me to ask some guys that could know how to do it.

I have tested to much code to post here but please give me any advices.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: You have to find a way to post your code here. Or in jsfiddle.  Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: I tried a lot of different code

Comment: Please post the code you tried last, it's also helpful to make a demo at www.jsfiddle.net so we can provide you with a working example :)